# How to print the below custom-defined data which is present inside the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, custom-data-type

Custom data class:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,val,count):
    self.val=val
    self.count=count
```

Creating dictionary and appending key + custom data:

```
arr=dict()
n=int(input("Enter Size:"))
for i in range(n):
n1=int(input("Key:"))
n2=int(input("value:"))
arr[n1]=Node(n1,0)
```

Giving error while printing the custom data:

```
for k,node in arr:
print(k,node.val,node.count)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: What's the error? can you include a traceback please

Comment: Iterate `arr.items()` instead of `arr`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the use of `n2` in your code? Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1.

```
for k in arr:
    print(k,arr[k].val,arr[k].count)
```

2. 

```
for k, node in arr.items():
        print(k,node.val,node.count)
```